# OEIS A002845: Number of distinct values taken by 2^2^...^2 (with n 2's and parentheses inserted in all possible ways)

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sequence, combinatorics, exponent

I am looking for a reasonably fast algorithm to calculate terms of the OEIS sequence [A002845](http://oeis.org/A002845). Let me restate its definition here.

Let ^ denote the exponentiation operator. Consider expressions of the form 2^2^...^2 having n 2's with parentheses inserted in all possible ways (the number of possible parenthesizations is given by [Catalan numbers](http://oeis.org/A000108)). Some of these expressions will have the same value, for example (2^2)^2=2^(2^2). We are interested in the number of distinct values for a given n.

There is an obvious brute-force solution through a direct calculation of these expressions, but it is clear that the required time and space quickly exceed all reasonable limits even for relatively small n. I'm interested in a polynomial-time solution to this problem.

Comment: There is a somewhat related question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103411/number-of-distinct-values-taken-by-alpha-alpha-dots-alpha-with

Comment: Have you read the linked papers? http://www.jstor.org/stable/2316312?seq=1 and http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2319392. Though I've only glanced at it, the former shows equivalence to some tree-based things that might be helpful.

Comment: Another related question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79442/

Comment: @Dougal: Yes, I've read those papers. Unfortunately, no algorithm is given there.

Comment: @Vladimir: are there any more examples of equal values? I suspect there are no except trivial ones, as 2^2^...^2 is growing very fast with the number of terms (but I cannot prove it).

Comment: @Vlad: (2^2)^(2^2) = ((2^2)^2)^2

Comment: The brute-force solution can be sped up via dynamic programming - augment the solution with a hashtable (e.g. {"2^2", 4}; {"2^(2^2)", 16}), so that you don't need to keep recomputing the sub-problems.  Have you looked into something like this?

Comment: Free copy of the paper (not all of us have jstor) http://oeis.org/A003018/a003018.pdf

Comment: I liked the question, just for curiosity, what is this useful for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just represent the numbers in iterated base 2: a `Num` has a (possibly empty) list of distinct children `x1,...,xp` of type `Num`, so that `Num([x1,...,xp]) == 2^x1 + ... + 2^xp`.

This defines a unique way to write a nonnegative integer; remember to sort the exponents so that comparison makes sense. The equalities:

- `2^x + 2^x == 2^(x+1) == Num([x+1])`
- `2^x + 2^y == Num([x,y])` when `x != y`
- `(2^2^x)^2^y == 2^2^(x+y) == Num([Num([x+y])])`

along with associativity/commutativity of addition allow you to add arbitrary numbers and compute `x^y` for numbers of the form 2^2^k; this class of numbers contains 2 (with k=0) and is closed under `^` so this guarantees that every number we need to manipulate is of this form.

Furthermore, the equalities defined above never increase the number of nodes in the tree, so all the `Num` are of size `O(n)`.

So the time complexity is actually `O(C * n^k)` which is quasi-linear in C (C is the (n-1)-th Catalan number).

Comment: I think this answer gets the closest to the solution of the problem. I am happy to award the bounty to its author.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution here involves dynamic programming, a difficult concept to grasp, but very efficient if done correctly.  The idea is to minimize the number of times you have to do a certain calculation, by remembering the results of calculations you've already done, and then using this knowledge to split the problem into a subset of simpler problems.

For example, in your 2^(2^2) = (2^2)^2 example, we can now remember this as two things that are equivalent to the value of 16. So now when we see this tacked on to 2^(2^(2^2)) = 2^((2^2)^2) we can very quickly identify each of these as 2 ^ 16, do the calculation once, and we now have two new equations to add to the list of values we never have to calculate again.

This may not seem to help much, however, when you end up with very long series of parenthesized questions, with even longer sets of equivalencies, it will save you a of time and complexity, in what are very long calculations for a computer to do on very large numbers.  Pseudo code below, I appologize, this is really broad psuedo code, this problem is pretty rough, so I didn't want to write out an entire algorithm.  Just really outlined the concept in more detail

```
 sortedEquivalencyVector;  //Sorted greatest first, so we are more likely to se longest matches

 function(expression)

    if(portion of expression exists)  //Remember, you can only do this from the end of the expression in toward the middle!
         replace value at end of expression that matches with its already computed value

    if(simplified version exists in vector) add original expression to vector
    else compute value and add it to the vector
 end
```

Comment: Still, even without recalculation, the values would grow extremely fast - it would take enormous time and memory to calculate such a value even once.

Comment: Yes, but just because a problem is hard does not mean that it is avoidable... the idea is to limit the number of long calculations to a minimum.  If you have an answer that avoids doing them completely why don't you provide it.

Comment: I do not have an answer, and I do not claim I have. But your post is not an answer either. You just gave some obvious recommendations that were already given in a comment to the question, and they do not help with the main obstacle to the solution - huge numbers. Nothing personal, but I just think this question is very interesting and deserves a real answer.

Comment: I actually completely disagree.  The question isn't directed at computing the value of 2^2^2^2^2^2, but it directed at the complexity of computing it for all of the combinations of parentheses.  One is an algorithmic problem directed at stack overlflow, the other is a mathematical problem, which isn't what the question was about "I'm interested in a polynomial-time solution to this problem." suggesting he is more concered about the big-oh complexity of the overall solution, than he is about simplifying one of the calculations of one instance.

Comment: I guess, overall, mine is the best solution on this board.  It doesn't necessarily deserve to be "accepted" if it is too computationally complex to be implemented, but it is still theoretically correct and doesn't deserve the down vote.

Comment: Useful thoughts, but unfortunately, not an answer. It could not be used to directly calculate the sequence in question.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which is much better than brute-force (but admittedly still expensive) is to use the concept of "standard form" in the first linked paper. Given an `n`,  generate each standard form of degree `n`, evaluate it, and keep all values in a set. At the end, check the size of the set.

The grammar for a standard form is

```
S -> (2 ^ P)
P -> (S * P)
P -> S
S -> 2
```

You start with an `S`, and at the end you should have `n` terminals (i.e. `2`s).